# I can't solve null object reference

Tags: android, null

I am in complex trouble that i can't solve.
[image]
I have two classes named ActivityA and ActivityB.

ActivityB uses method in ActivityA named "A".

So "A" has to be static.

In "A" uses function named "ShowSuccessDialog"

and it also has to be static.

When I start the App, there is an error that

"non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

I have tried to replace ActivityA.this with getContext(), getActivity()

But it doesn't work.

I googled and found making instance could be help,

But i don't have any clue about it.

Please solve this problem

[image]
************************** added & edited **************************
I will add more information.

My app is consist of 1 main activity and 3 fragment

ActivityA is a mainActivity that has connecting bluetooth, sending and receiving data.

ActivityB is a fragment that needs data receiving through bluetooth

ActivityC is a fragment that receiving and sending data and has another functions.

I have tried to define bluetooth functions on the activity and use bluetooth fuctions by refering activity.

So ActivityA is MainActivity, ActivityB is fragmentB

A is connecting function, and B is receiving Data.

I am not good at programming, So this is the best what i can do.

So I want to solve this problem by editing little. ;(

Comment: Don't use static methods in Activities like that. Why can't you just show the `Dialog` in `ActivityB`?

Comment: Thanks for you opinion. But dialog is only needed in ActivityA.

Comment: But aren't you trying to show it from `ActivityB`? Doesn't that mean that you need it in `ActivityB`?

Comment: I agree with @MikeM. you should not be trying to call it from `ActivityB` if `ActivityA` needs it (or vice versa), either create the same method with different (or the same) implementation in both of these activities OR create a (potentially static) helper object/util for this

Comment: I added more information about my situation. Sorry for my writing skills

Comment: Activities and Fragments are very different things that are not interchangeable. It's not really correct to call a Fragment `ActivityB`. Call it `FragmentB` instead. Just FYI. Your question makes more sense, now that we know it's a `Fragment` inside an `Activity`.

Comment: I solved this Problem!!!!! https://hashcode.co.kr/questions/96/%EC%95%88%EB%93%9C%EB%A1%9C%EC%9D%B4%EB%93%9C%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-static%EB%A9%94%EC%86%8C%EB%93%9C%EB%A5%BC-%EC%8D%A8%EC%84%9C-context%EC%96%BB%EC%9D%84%EC%88%98-%EC%9E%88%EB%82%98%EC%9A%94
Instead of getApplicationContext, use 'this'

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is not good practice to do something like this. But for learning how to do it you can do something like this:

1- Change the method `ShowSuccessDialog` signature and the body like this:

```
private static void ShowSuccessDialog(Context context) {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
}
```

2- In method `A`:

```
private void A() {
    ShowSuccessDialog(ActivityA.this);
}
```

3- In ActivityB call the method like this:

```
ShowSuccessDialog(ActivityB.this);
```

Comment: I wrote wrong that Activity B is actually fragment. But that's not problem this time.
A can't use this because is belongs to static usercallback A ;(